# Vim's Omnicompletion with Python just doesn't work

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, omnicomplete

I've searched around for an hour, both on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. Alas! Please help. Vim's omnicompletion just *doesn't work*.

1. I have Vim 7.2 compiled with Python support.
2. `filetype plugin on` is in my `.vimrc`.
3. When a `.py` file is open, `:echo &omnifunc` prints `pythoncomplete#Complete`.
4. I'm working with a large project and I have a `tags` file generated with `exhuberant-ctags`. It's in Vim's `ctags` path. I can test it by typing <kbd>^]</kbd> on a symbol and I'm then taken to the symbols' definition.
5. **Update 1:** All of my project's code is in the python-in-Vim's path. I can `:python import myproject` successfully.

Now, anywhere I try <kbd>C-x C-o</kbd>, all I get is:

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 2:** When I type <kbd>C-x C-o C-n</kbd> at the module-level, Vim displays a completion popup with a few module-level constants from other modules in my project. But it's only constants (symbols capital letters) and the completion still doesn't work anywhere else.

**Update 3:** I've found that <kbd>C-x C-o</kbd> at the top of the file starts some kind of omnicompletion, and completion for `pprint.` brings up the menu and quick-reference of everything in the `pprint` module. However, none of my own module's imports are being completed.

**Update 4, one year later:** I gave up and learned Emacs. I have been to the dark side, the mystical land of intrigue and spice, and I say to thee that I have found The Way.

**Update 5, two years later:** I went back to Vim. Emacs is beautiful, but even after 1.5 years of Emacs, I'm still faster at getting work done in Vim. I've stopped writing Python for now, however, and can't test how well these suggestions work.

Comment: You might want to try this, if you haven't already: http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/

Comment: @jellybean -- Good link, thanks! I already used `minibufexpl.vim` and `Taglist.vim`, but the `TODO` listing thing would be a great addition.

Comment: Never found an answer to this :(

Comment: Vim 7.3.45 omni completion for python worked out of the box with `+python` and `filetype plugin on` of course.

Answer (score 12):

What module contains the symbol you are trying to complete? Is it in the python stdlib? Or is it a third-party module?

Make sure that the module/package is in the PYTHONPATH.

In Vim, do:

```
:python import sys
:python print sys.path
```

To add the module's directory:

```
:python sys.path.append("/path/to/directory/")
```

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks. These are symbols from my project's code. Yes, the path is in Vim's Python's path. I've updated the question description.

Comment: So, is it not possible to have autocompletion in your own libraries?

Comment: Yes it is possible, just make sure that the modules and packages are somewhere in Python's module search path.

Comment: If you use virtualenv for your project, make sure that you switched to  your environment in terminal before you will run vim(in the same terminal!). Check your sys.path in vim command line when you switched to env - modules that you need to autocomplete must be there.

Comment: I tried this but got "Sorry, the command is not available in this version". But running `vim --version` showed +python3 and -python (python3 support but no python2) with my vim and the above commands work simply by changing `python` to `python3`.

Comment: I had to use :py3 instead of :python. However it did not solve my problem :-)

Answer (score 10):

Since you were prudent and made certain your code is reachable by the PYTHONPATH, per codeape's suggestion, is there a possibility that you are running into the [`import` bug for Vim Python omni-complete](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/58191d176ebd9722/d9cd31cee304b7df?pli=1)? This bug still exists as of Vim 7.2.245.

Essentially, if **any** import statement fails in the file you are working in, regardless of whether it's wrapped in a `Try-Except` clause, it will completely break omni-completion. It should be fairly easy to check for this, since most imports occur at the very beginning of the file.

If you do decide that this bug is the cause of your troubles, your options include:

- making sure that the modules you import are on the system path, not just the project files
- commenting out any `import` statements that fail
- fixing the bug
- using [ropevim](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim) as your completion method
- using a different editor; Netbeans IDE has Python support, and the [jVi plugin](http://jvi.sourceforge.net/) is rather good if you're a Vim addict like myself (don't let the 1990s look of the home page fool you)

Comment: I too have run into this issue of any import problem just trashing my omni-complete entirely.  I think even "warnings" about a module having already been imported from a different location in the project will crash your vim session when you try to omni-complete it.

Comment: Bodhi, have a look at ropevim. (See the link in my edited answer above.)

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like the questioner has long since gone to the dark side*, but for what it's worth I've just had this symptom, and in my case the cause was that a module I was using relied on Python 2.7 but my version of Vim was compiled with Python 2.5.

To diagnose I tried `:python import mymodule`, which failed with an error about importing a dependent module. Then `:python import dependentmodule` which failed with the next step in the chain. And so on & so on, until it failed trying to import a system module that was new since Python 2.7. Problem found.

To solve, I just did `sudo port install vim +python27`. But that's for OSX. YMMV.

(* I'm kidding. Emacs users are our friends. It's the people programming in Notepad we all have to save...)

Comment: This is one of the most promising solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting..I have a strong feeling I'm running into this too!  I'm using MacVim (Macports build) with python support, and it's linked to (also Macports) Python 2.5  I'm working on a project that is Python 2.7 and I'm sure we import some 2.7-only modules.  When mine fails on tab completing (Supertab plugin), it actually SEGV faults my vim session!  I'm hoping reinstalling MacVim with python2.7 will solve it. Cheers!

Comment: Felt a report back was worthwhile - my Supertab plugin and omnicompletion work *much* better now, but *still* do crash my macvim session sometimes :(  It appears to be whenever there is something bad in the import sequence the completion is looking through (like a potential circular import for example). Things are looking up, anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are not doing anything wrong. Python omni completion **does not use a tags
file**. This is on purpose. You do not need to make a tags file for omni
completion. You can still make a tags file for the usual tag-stack jumping, but
it is ignored by omni completion.

It took me a long time to figure this out because *C omni completion does use
a tags file*. Python omni completion works differently.

You can quickly observe this behavior by attempting omni completion in a Python file with `python` filetype and then with `c` filetype.

First `:set filetype=python` (this is the default), then `:echo &omnifunc`. Omni complete ignores the tags file because `&omnifunc` is `python3complete#Complete`, which does not use the tags file.

Note there is no `omnifunc` set if your Vim is not built to support Python. Check for Python support.

Here is an example showing **no Python support**:

```
vim --version | grep python
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           -python3           +virtualedit
```

Now `:set filetype=c` and `:echo &omnifunc`. Vim treats the Python script as a C file, so `&omnifunc` is `ccomplete#Complete`, which uses the tags file. Of course treating Python files like C files is not the solution!

Below are:

- two examples of how to do Python omni completion
- where the `&omnifunc` (syntaxcomplete#Complete) Vimscripts are implemented
- how `preview` window behavior differs between a tags file preview (`:pta`) and
  the omni complete preview.

There is also tag completion: `<C-x><C-]>`. If you already use a `tags` file and want Vim to complete using those tags, `<C-x><C-]>` is the completion you are looking for, not `<C-x><C-o>`.

But I encourage you to read on. Omni completion does more than tag completion:

1. Omni completion recognizes module names and auto completes using the correct Python syntax. For example, if you `import numpy as np`, then `np.a<C-x><C-o>` presents a menu of `numpy` functions starting with letter 'a'. Tag completion only auto-completes a match in the tags file.
2. Omni completion populates the preview window with documentation. Tag completion does not open a preview window.
3. And, for Python, omni completion does not require updating a tags file!

## Example 1: omni complete to match a pattern in this file

Python omni completion requires that the Python script you are editing is
working Python code. Here is a simple example with a local variable:

```py
foo_name_I_expect_omni_completion
```

This one-line script *does not run* (my variable name is not defined), so if I
edit this script and attempt to omni complete:

```py
foo_name_I_expect_omni_completion
foo_name_<C-x><C-o>
```

I get the "Pattern not found" message.

This is infuriating because the pattern it should match is literally on the
line above!

But all we need to make omni completion work is change this to **valid**
Python code:

```py
foo_name_I_expect_omni_completion = 2
foo_name_<C-x><C-o>
```

Now omni completion works!

Note: an **empty script docstring** (the doctsring at the top of the script) also causes the "Pattern not found" message. Either erase the empty script docstring or put any text at all in the script docstring and omni completion works again.

## Example 2: omni complete to match a pattern in an imported module

As a second example, omni completion also works if the pattern to match is in
another file, as long as that file is visible (with an `import` statement) to
the script being edited.

Again, I'll use `foo_name_I_expect_omni_completion=2`. I save the file with this
one-liner as `mymodule.py`. Now in a new file, `example.py`, I import
`mymodule`:

```py
import mymodule
```

Once I've typed `import mymodule`, `i_<C-x><C-o>` works on
the module name:

```py
import mymodule
mym<C-x><C-o>
```

Omni complete turns this into:

```py
import mymodule
mymodule.
```

and a menu of patterns pops up (see `:h completeopt` for configuring the menu
behavior), at which point I can do the usual `<C-n><C-y>` to select the first
item on the list and exit omni complete back to insert mode.

```py
import mymodule
mymodule.foo_name_I_expect_omni_completion
```

## If omni complete seems broken, check that the imported module is executable

If omni completion seems *unable* to see an imported module, it is because the
module you are importing is not executable.

Unlike the toy example above, this is hard to track down if the imported module
also imports packages and you have multiple versions of Python with different
packages installed in each version.

For example, I have 3.6 and 3.7 installed, but I'd only installed a certain
package on 3.6. And that same package was imported by the module I was importing
in the script I was trying to edit with omni complete.

Somehow, python3.6 was my default python3 from bash, but python3.7 was my
default from Vim. So the module *seemed* valid when I ran it from bash, because
my python3.6 installation had the necessary package.

Check which version of Python Vim is using:

```
:py3 print(sys.version)
```

Also check `sys.path`, as explained in the answer by codeape:

```
:py3 print(sys.path)
```

I have many installations of Python, and every Python installation has its own `USER_SITE` path.

```
:py3 import site; print(site.USER_SITE)
```

I use one `USER_SITE` folder and find a way to point each Python installation at it. For the Python installation Vim omni-complete uses, I do this by editing the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

In my case, my one active `USER_SITE` is for Python 3.7, and Vim is using Python 3.6, so I put this in my `.bashrc`:

```bash
# Python USERSITE folder
pkg=$HOME/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

# Add to PYTHONPATH for Vim omni-complete to see packages I wrote
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$pkg
```

## Documentation

I figured this out by tracking down the Vim scripts that do the completion.

From Vim help:

```
:h compl-omni-filetypes
```

> The file used for {filetype} should be autoload/{filetype}complete.vim
> in 'runtimepath'.  Thus for "java" it is autoload/javacomplete.vim.

These `autoload/{filetype}complete.vim` files are in your Vim installation. For example, here are my C and Python files:

```bash
/usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/ccomplete.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/python3complete.vim
```

Alternatively, call `:echo &omnifunc` and find the Vimscript on GitHub:
https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/

I started to suspect my fundamental misunderstanding of the problem when I found the word `tag` does not appear in the `python3complete.vim` file :)

## Omni complete has a special `preview` behavior

I've always been confused by the behavior of the preview window. *Omni complete* has a different `preview` behavior from tags.

First, to get a preview window with `omni complete`, Vim `completeopt` option must contain `preview` and either `menu` or `menuone`.

`completeopt` defaults to `menu,preview`. To set options explicitly, e.g.,
to use `menuone` instead on `menu`:

```
set completeopt=menuone,preview
```

`menuone` makes a menu always appear, even if there is only one pattern that matches. With `menu`, the menu does not appear for a single match, so neither does the `preview` window. Using `menuone` guarantees the `preview` window pops up.

Turn off `preview` to prevent the window split during omni complete:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```

Notice that the `preview` behavior for `omni complete` (which opens when you highlight a menu item) is different from the `preview` behavior for tags (which you open with `<C-w>}` or `:pta`)

- tag-preview opens the code in the preview window
- omni-complete-preview opens documentation

Omni complete's `preview` shows different things depending on the item
highlighted in the completion menu. If it is a variable, the pydoc for its
datatype is shown; if it is a function, its docstring is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Having updated to Fedora 16 (but still compiling vim from source), omni completion stopped working with the same message as above.  I "fixed" it by re-maping the keys.

```
inoremap <C-space> <C-x><C-o>
```

in `~/.vimrc` and now it works again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with omni completion not working. In my case it turned out that the minibufexpl.vim plugin was interfering with omni completion. Here is how I found out:

Normal keyword completion works. Omni complete does not work for any language, not just Python. omnifunc is set correctly. After I C-X C-O, nothing happens. I do ":py print globals()" and it is clear that the pythoncomplete was not loaded. I can ":call pythoncomplete#Complete(1, '')" and see it get loaded. To me this rules out it being a Vim issue. It seems something is interfering with keymapping or otherwise intercept the omni completion request. So I start to disable my plugins one by one. It turns out the culprit in my case is "minibufexpl". I have the Holgado version from github.

It looks like there are many open issues with MBE according to the issue tracker on github and there hasn't been any progress since early 2012. I am just going to disable it for now so I can use auto completion. Meanwhile I will just add the following to my vimrc to keep multiple modified buffers open at the same time and use a simple key sequence to cycle through them (MBE more intelligently select the buffers to cycle through but seems too heavy-handed for a simple problem):

```
set hidden
noremap <C-TAB> :bnext<CR>
noremap <C-S-TAB> :bprev<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `<C_x><C-]>` ?

Answer (score 0):

`c-x c-n` works to get the list of members of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I used supertab (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643)

Since C-x C-o is a bit frustrating to use

in .vimrc:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-o>"
```

then just use Tabb for omnicompletion

Comment: I fixed an issue by adding:

        `let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"`

to my .vimrc (SuperTab plugin configuration)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python2, make sure you

```
sudo apt-get install vim.nox-py2
```

and use vim.nox-py2 instead of vim.