# Vim,omnicomplete and python documentation

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

I started to learn Python, and I tried to setup my vim for it. I have `vim 7.3.5.3`, it has omnicompletion and I downloaded `pyflakes`. I read [this article](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/) 
and it says that omnicompletion should also display some documentation (there is also an image with `string.atoi` and some documentation), but when I try something like this:

```
import string
string.
```

and do <kbd>CTRL-x</kbd><kbd>CTRL-o</kbd> I get the proper listing, but I don't get any documentation.

Should I install other plugins or change some configuration file?

**EDIT**:
I needed to install `supertabs` to get the effect I wanted.

Comment: you should apply patch to fix a bug which can't complete with "from xxx import yyy": https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/Dnb4OcDriJ0/discussion

Answer (score 3):

To enable code(omni) completion, add this line to your vimrc ($HOME/vimrc):

```
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

If it doesn’t work then, you’ll need this [plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542).

Comment: I tried it and I still don't have the window with documentation, I tried to get something like this: http://blog.dispatched.ch/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/omnicompletion.png As I said, I get the listing(Formatter,Template,atof etc.) but I want to get this small window that shows documentation also.

Comment: please check this: http://www.mohdshakir.net/2007/12/27/enable-vim-code-python-auto-complete too! It describes how to do this by using the pydiciton plugin that you can download it from here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote now. You don't seem to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Check my plugin: https://github.com/klen/python-mode

Rope omnicompletion from the box. Also many others features.

Answer (score 1):

Omni completion `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O` works in Vim without installing plugins, but only if you satisfy these three conditions:

1. Vim is compiled with `+python3`
2. Python3 is installed
3. for the Python packages you want to omni-complete:

   - the package is installed
   - the script you are editing has an `import` statement for the Python package
   - if doing `import numpy as np`, you are doing `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O` after typing `np.`, not `numpy.`

The Python3 omni completion is defined in the `python3complete.vim` that comes with Vim.

```
:new
:set filetype=python
:echo &omnifunc
python3complete#Complete
```

I found this in my Vim installation here:

```sh
/usr/share/vim/vim81/autoload/python3complete.vim
```

## Details

### 1. Vim compiled with +python3

`:ve` to check Vim version and enabled features. Here is the relevant output when I run `:ve`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jul 28 2019 15:01:57)
...
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
+python3/dyn
...
```

### 2. Python installation

This is easy to confuse when there are multiple Python installations.
For example, I have a *Windows Python3 installation*:

- *Windows Python3* runs from PowerShell

```bsh
PS> python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

- *Windows Python3* runs from Cygwin bash

```sh
$ python.exe
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

- *Windows Python3* **does not** run from the Cygwin Vim command line

  ```
  :python3
  ```

  - of course I can use `:!python.exe` for Vim to run `python.exe` in bash

  ```
  :!python.exe
  Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
  ```

  - but that does not help **omni completion**
  - for **omni completion** Vim needs to be able to Python3 *directly from the Vim command line*

**Test Vim can call Python3:**

```
:py3 print("hey")
hey
```

I had to install Python *with the Cygwin package manager* to get the output `hey`.

### 3. Python package installation

If you have the mutliple Python installation problem, then also install another copy of the Python packages you want to omni-complete for.

For example, I installed the Python packages with the Cygwin package manager.

If the Python package is not available through your package manager, clone a copy of the package repository at the path identified by `site.USER_SITE`. This is part of the package search path, so omni completion searches in this path as well.

Find out the `USER_SITE` path from Vim:

```
: py3 import site; print(site.getusersitepackages())
```

The path should look something like this:

```
/home/myname/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Alternatively, check from bash:

```
$ python3.7 -m site --user-site
/home/myname/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

*Note the path is defined even it is does not exist. You need to create the path if this is the first time putting a package there.*

With the above conditions satisfied, omni completion works. Start a `.py` file (or just open a new buffer and `:set filetype=python`), then try typing the following:

```py
import numpy as np
np.CTRL-X_CTRL-O
```

The omni-complete window pops-up for cycling through with `CTRL-N` (next) `CTRL-P` (previous).

There is additional confusion because `python3complete` does not use a tags file like `ccomplete` does. Please see my solution to this post: [Vim's Omnicompletion with Python just doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084875/vims-omnicompletion-with-python-just-doesnt-work/57861300#57861300)